# A way to shorten operator use in Java

Tags: java, arrays, operators

As a college assignment, I was asked to make our own version of conway's game of life. To this end, I must take each element of a multidimensional array (here represented by xycoords[i][j]) and analyze whether or not the 8 adjacent spaces (if any) are "alive" (equal to 1, of course).

I end up with these series of *ifs* that basically check each adjacent element, and if it equals 1, then add it to a variable called *xycount*.

The problem comes when such thing as j-1, i+1, etc are *null* because they are outside of the array. The only way I can think of to stop this is to put exceptions on each case, which makes a very long and tedious code.

is there a simpler way to do this? I can present this in the long form but I want to improve it as much as I can.

Thanks.

```
for (int i=0; i<(xycoords.length); i++ ) {
                for (int j=0;j<xycoords[i].length;j++){
                    if (xycoords[i-1][j-1] == 1) xycount++;
                    if (xycoords[i-1][j] == 1) xycount++;
                    if (xycoords[i-1][j+1] == 1) xycount++;
                    if (xycoords[i][j-1] == 1) xycount++;
                    if (xycoords[i][j+1] == 1) xycount++;
                    if (xycoords[i+1][j-1] == 1) xycount++;
                    if (xycoords[i+1][j] == 1) xycount++;
                    if (xycoords[i+1][j+1] == 1) xycount++;
```

Comment: You could write a loop that went from i-1 to i+1, containing a loop that went from j-1 to j+1. Then check whether you're still in the array , and if so, look up the value of the cell and add it to xycount.

Comment: are they null or are they out of array bounds?

Comment: Also, consider using a board that has extra cells all around the real cells - top, left, right and bottom. Initialise these to zero and never change them. Then in your loop go from 1 to length -1. Now the adjacent cells are always within bounds and you don't need to check.